# Autofac, OrchardProject and AsyncControllers

Tags: autofac, asynccontroller

I'm working on trying to get an AsyncController to work in OrchardProject.  The current version I'm using is 2.2.4.9.0.

I've had 2 people eyeball my code:   http://www.pastie.org/2117952  (AsyncController) which works fine in a regular MVC3 vanilla application.

Basically, I can route to IndexCompleted, but I can't route to Index.  I am going to assume i'm missing something in the Autofac configuration of the overall project.

I think the configuration is in the global.asax: http://pastie.org/2118008

What I'm looking for is some guidance on if this is the correct way to implement autofac for AsyncControllers, or if there is something/someplace else I need to implement/initialize/etc.

~Dan

Comment: What version of Autofac is this?

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear from the question whether that was an Orchard version number or an Autofac number :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard appears to register its own `IActionInvoker`, called `Orchard.Mvc.Filters.FilterResolvingActionInvoker`.

This class derives from `ControllerActionInvoker`. At a guess, in order to support async actions, it should instead derive from `AsyncControllerActionInvoker`.

Hope this helps!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

The Autofac setup looks ok, and as long as you can navigate to *something* I cannot say that your assumption makes sense. Also, the pattern you are using for initialization in global.asax is used by [others](http://litemedia.info/automate-deploy-of-your-orchard-cms-to-azure) too.

The `AsyncController` requires that async methods come in pairs, in your case `IndexAsync` & `IndexCompleted`. These together represent the `Index` action. When you say you can navigate to IndexCompleted, do you mean that you open a url "..../IndexCompleted"?

Also, and this I cannot confirm from any documentation, but I would guess that `AsyncController` requires that all actions are async. Thus, your `NewMessage` action causes trouble and should be converted to an async `NewMessageAsync` & `NewMessageCompleted` pair.

Answer (score 0):

I did too needed to have `AsyncController` which I easily changed `FilterResolvingActionInvoker` to be based on `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` instead of `ControllerActionInvoker`.

But there was other problems because of automatic transaction disposal after completion of request. In `AsyncController` starting thread and the thread that completes the request can be different which throws following exception in Dispose method of `TransactionManager` class:

**A `TransactionScope` must be disposed on the same thread that it was created.**

This exception is suppressed without any logging and really was hard to find out. In this case session remains not-disposed and subsequent sessions will timeout.
So I made dispose method public on `ITransactionManager` and now in my `AsyncController`, whenever I need a query to database I wrap it in:

```cs
using (_services.TransactionManager) {
    .....
}
```

new TransactionManager :

```cs
public interface ITransactionManager : IDependency, IDisposable {
    void Demand();
    void Cancel();
}

public class TransactionManager : ITransactionManager {
    private TransactionScope _scope;
    private bool _cancelled;

    public TransactionManager() {
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public void Demand() {
        if (_scope == null) {
            Logger.Debug("Creating transaction on Demand");
            _scope = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
                new TransactionOptions { 
                    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted 
                });
            _cancelled = false;
        }
    }

    void ITransactionManager.Cancel() {
        Logger.Debug("Transaction cancelled flag set");
        _cancelled = true;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        if (_scope != null) {
            if (!_cancelled) {
                Logger.Debug("Marking transaction as complete");
                _scope.Complete();
            }

            Logger.Debug("Final work for transaction being performed");
            try {
                _scope.Dispose();
            }
            catch {
                // swallowing the exception
            }
            Logger.Debug("Transaction disposed");
        }
        _scope = null;
    }
}
```

Please notice that I have made other small changes to `TransactionManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the AsyncControllerActionInvoker route as well to no avail.  I would get intermittent errors from Orchard itself with the following errors:

```
Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - An unexpected exception was caught
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.ReflectedAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__3e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - While preparing SELECT this_.Id as Id236_2_, this_.Number as Number236_2_,...<blah blah blah>
NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope.
```

So I don't think just wrapping your own database calls with a transaction object will help.  The innards of Orchard would have to modified as well.

Go vote for this issue if you want AsyncControllers supported in Orchard:

https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18012